# Data keyfunction filter always returning first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

**Short version: DOM elements for first data element in bound d3.js JSON dataset is always showing and can't be removed, all other elements behaving as expected.**

Working with d3.js, trying to generate a standard schedule setup that is subsequently populated with varied datasets. Pull some nested JSON data, standard enter/update/exit format to modify schedule display. Need the structure (struct) data available elsewhere, so assign it to a global after pulling before filtering and attaching:

```
d3.json('php/controllers/sched_struct_endpoint.php?set=' + set, function(d) {
        struct = d;
        drawAxis();
    });
```

(drawAxis() is the redraw function, code below from that function). Everything is working fine, except that the first element (schedule display for Sunday) is always bound/showing - all other elements add/remove exactly as expected. Think the issue might be with my data filter; using day number as the key function, intending to display all days if 'All' is selected, or only the specified day if a single day is selected. Sunday is day 1, Monday 2, etc. - but the resulting data display is always [1,2] or [1,5] - never just [2] or [5]. Display all [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] works as expected.

```
dayData = chartAxis.selectAll(".titleDay")
        .data(struct, function(d) { return day === 'All' ? d.day_number : d.day_number === day; } );

    var titleDay = dayData.enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class","titleDay");

    titleDay
        .attr("id", function(d) { return d.day_name;})
        .attr("transform", function(d,i) { return "translate(0," + (day == 'All' ? i * elem_height * 1.05 : 0) + ")" ; })

    titleDay.append("rect")
        .attr("width",daywidth)
        .attr("height", elem_height);

    titleDay.append("text")
        .text(function(d) { return d.day_name; })
        .attr("text-anchor","middle")
        .attr("transform", function(d,i) { return "translate(45," + (elem_height / 2) + ")" ; });
```

... (more code adding additional schedule elements) ...

```
dayData.exit().remove();
```

Experimentally adding

```
d3.selectAll(".titleDay").remove();
```

to the beginning of the redraw function will temporarily remove the first element, but then it gets added back in immediately.

Sample data structure (array of 7 objects, each with day name, number, and list of available resources):

```
[
    {
    "day_number": "1",
    "day_name": "Sunday",
    "resources": [
        {
            "resource_id": "OR01",
            "resource_name": "OR 01",
    ...
```

Comment: Any chance it could be a syntax error in the JSON? Maybe Sunday is formatted differently, or has an extra curly brace somewhere?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use the key function to filter data -- this is not what it does. You probably want something like `.data(struct.filter(function(d) { return day === "All" || d.day_number === day; }), function(d) { return d.day_number; })`.

Comment: @Pikamander2 - Thanks for the quick response! No, I've run the JSON through jsonlint and comes out valid, and the data matches exactly - the JSON is programmatically generated from a database using the same function for each day/resource, and Sunday displays correctly when 'All' days are selected. The only issue here is matching the day number (1,2,3...) to the interface select value (1,2,3..) when only a single value is selected. Thinking it might be binding the first element by some default behavior in d3.js I'm unaware of and handling incorrectly...

Comment: @LarsKotthoff - that did it, thanks! Odd, I had read a tutorial on keyfunction filtering vs. the filter function and it did seem to be working as the author described, but that was the only instance where I found that function described, so makes sense in retrospect that perhaps the feature was being abused. First post on stackoverflow, is it possible to mark a comment as correct response?

Comment: I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use the key function to filter data -- this is not what it does. You probably want something like

```
.data(struct.filter(function(d) { return day === "All" || d.day_number === day; }),
      function(d) { return d.day_number; })
```

This will filter the data according to the criteria that you specified and then do the matching by `day_number`.